# How to fix LDA model coherence score runtime Error?

Tags: python, nlp, runtime-error, lda, topic-modeling

text='Alice is a student.She likes studying.Teachers are giving a lot of homewok.'

## I am trying to get topics from a simple text(like above) with coherance score.This is my LDA model:

```
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_lemmatized)
texts = data_lemmatized
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                                           id2word=id2word,
                                           num_topics=5, 
                                           random_state=100,
                                           update_every=1,
                                           chunksize=100,
                                           passes=10,
                                           alpha='auto',
                                           per_word_topics=True)
# Print the Keyword in the 10 topics
pprint(lda_model.print_topics())
doc_lda = lda_model[corpus]
```

## When i try to run this coherance model:

```
coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=data_lemmatized, dictionary=id2word, 
coherence='c_v')
coherence_lda = coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
print('\nCoherence Score: ', coherence_lda)
```

## I am  supposed to get this king of output-> Coherence Score:  0.532947587081

I get this error:
raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

What should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. Adding 'Coherence Model' inside if__name__=="**main**" resolved the issue for me.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

     coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=data_lemmatized, 
                                                          dictionary=id2word, 
                                                              coherence='c_v')
     coherence_lda = coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
     print('\nCoherence Score: ', coherence_lda)
```

Comment: it works. Thanks! What a strange issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue when running gensim Nmf and the way to fix it was to change from coherence='c_v' to coherence='u_mass'

Answer (score 0):

You can use coherence='c_v' without problem.
My answer is quite similar to AKHILA one. But I call freeze_support() in the main process and start the method with support for Windows.

Consider the structure from the beginning:

```
# imports
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
import ...

# general constants and variables
...

# functions definition
def ...
...

def ...
...

# main function
def principal(): # can be another name
...
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  freeze_support()
  Process(target=main).start()
```